# Detect the button click of the Toast notification in UWP

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

My UWP application will send two different type of notifications as Generic and reminder toast. In Generic toast I have two button.one button will launch URL and another button will lauch the settings page. In the second type I have snooze button. I want to detetct the button click of the toast notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the **arguments** attribute inside the  element of the notification. After this you can read the arguments in app's OnActivated.

For example:

1) The notification:

```
 <actions>
    <action content="launch" arguments="launch"  />
    <action content="settings" arguments="settings" />
  </actions>
```

2) The code inside your app:

```
async protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    //Find out if this is activated from a toast;
    If (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
    {
        var toastArgs = args as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;
        var arguments = toastArgs.Arguments;
    //...
```

Some good resources are available from here:

[Adaptive and interactive toast notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts)

[MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/976ee70d-a2dc-46e0-b1fb-8d2d18cce343/uwphow-to-create-an-event-handler-to-the-buttons-from-toast-notification-xml?forum=wpdevelop)

[Full Sample from GitHub (by Microsoft)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications)